# Is it possible to execute a script when a monitor is power on/off?

Tags: linux, display, script, hdmi

I would like to start / stop some applications when I power on / off my HDMI monitor.

My computer is always on but some graphical applications are not needed when nobody can watch.
It consumes more power and makes the fan noisier (my bed is in the same room so it's really annoying).

The computer is an HTPC with Kodi and I dont have a real keyboard on it, only a remote, so starting or closing applications is not that easy. I would like to try to do it automatically if possible.

I wonder if it is possible to use something as inotify ?
But I don't know if monitors are listed in /dev and what file it could be.

Has anyone done something like that before ?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, a [script can *first* turn off the display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line), and *then* run your specific application. Most monitors enter power-saving mode when there is no signal, so that should accomplish your goal.

In Ubuntu, the command is:

`xset -display :0.0 dpms force off`

or

`sudo vbetool dpms off`

To turn it on through Terminal,

`

Try these commands...

To Turn Off:

xset -display :0.0 dpms force off

To Turn On:

`xset -display :0.0 dpms force on`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I don't get it though, because what I want is not turn off the display device, but detect when its status change (detect if there is any output device on HDMI ports), in order to do some actions automatically. That way if I turn off my TV, Kodi will stop, and it will start when I turn on the TV.

Comment: This would work in reverse, i.e. you would in effect shut the TV from the PC keyboard with the script.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue is you have to run this approx 1 min via cron or etc because it doesn't generate an event that I know of in linux.  Therefore your there will be a delay of up to 60 seconds before the change has been detected.

You have several options hdmi cec.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109288/61312

If your device doesn't support hdmi cec directly through the video card you can buy a USB dongle.

https://www.pulse-eight.com/p/104/usb-hdmi-cec-adapter

Note:  I have not personally tested this device, but it has an average of 5* with 747 users so they must be doing something right.

Summarizing my link above:

> echo 'scan' | cec-client -s -d 1
>
> Take the device's address from this information. And now ask for the
>   status of the device.
>
> echo 'pow 0.0.0.0' | cec-client -s -d 1 |grep power
>
> The answer is something like this:
>
> ```
> power status: on or
> power status: standby
> ```

There are other options.

Using if you have wifi or get a usb wifi dongle:

You can get a kasa outlet strip hs300

Then you can install python

Then 
https://github.com/p-doyle/Python-KasaSmartPowerStrip

then write some code

```
from KasaSmartPowerStrip import SmartPowerStrip

#Replace 1.1.1.1 with kasa's wifi ip
power_strip = SmartPowerStrip('1.1.1.1')

print(power_strip.get_realtime_energy_info(plug_num=1))
```

Now all it takes is a few more lines of code to compare the monitors power usage between its on and off status.  Most monitors take <10 watts off and >20 watts on.

So if your monitor is >20 watts send a command to kill/end the software in question.